# Python SQLAlchemy executes via MySQL terminal but not via engine.execute

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Howdie do,

I have a very simple select statement:

```
select order_id as oid2, ship_update_date, status_type
from tracking_update
where status_type like 'M'
```

I've converted this into a function and the raw SQL is:

```
for letter in status_filter:
    db.session.execute(
        'select order_id, ship_update_date, status_type '
        'from tracking_update where status_type = %s' % letter
)
```

However, when this SQL is executed via Python, I receive the following:

```
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'P' in 'where clause'") [SQL: u'select order_id, ship_update_date, status_type from tracking_update where status_type = "P"']
```

It's clearly passing the letter, but why will is it treating my search value as a column?

Answer (score 0):

Howdie do,

I changed the code to the following:

```
"select order_id, ship_update_date, status_type "
                    "from tracking_update where status_type=:param", {"param":letter}
```

My parameter is now being passed properly.

Thank you Session API documenation:

[SQL alchemy session documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.execute)